# Passing a template to deque

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to write a container class for deque to make a circular buffer (using deque is important here since the class is replacing a vector and does need to be used like one here). I don't want to have to make the container class specific to a specific deque; that is, I want the class to be a template class and the deque to get the templated type. However, my code gives me use of undefined type errors when it compiles (c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\deque(795): error C2027: use of undefined type 'dequeClass').

The code:

```
#pragma once

#include <deque>

template<typename dequeClass>
class CircularDeque {
public:
    CircularDeque(int newMax);
    ~CircularDeque();
    void push_front(dequeClass&& val);
    void push_front(const dequeClass& val);
    void push_back(dequeClass&& val);
    void push_back(const dequeClass& val);
    std::deque<dequeClass> que;
    int getMax();
    void setMax(int newMax);
private:
    unsigned int max;
};

CircularDeque<class dequeClass>::CircularDeque(int newMax) {
    max = newMax;
}

void CircularDeque<class dequeClass>::push_front(dequeClass&& val) {
    que.push_front(val);
    if(que.size() > max) {
        que.pop_back();
    }
}

void CircularDeque<class dequeClass>::push_front(const dequeClass& val) {
    que.push_front(val);
    if(que.size() > max) {
        que.pop_back();
    }
}

void CircularDeque<class dequeClass>::push_back(dequeClass&& val) {
    que.push_back(val);
    if(que.size() > max) {
        que.pop_front();
    }
}

void CircularDeque<class dequeClass>::push_back(const dequeClass& val) {
    que.push_back(val);
    if(que.size() > max) {
        que.pop_front();
    }
}

int CircularDeque<class dequeClass>::getMax() {
    return max;
}

void CircularDeque<class dequeClass>::setMax(int newMax) {
    max = newMax;
}
```

Anyone know what I can do here?

Comment: If you are just trying to specialize the behavior of a `std::deque`, why not just inherit from it?  As long as you don't add any data members, you won't need the virtual destructor, so doing it through inheritance would remove a lot of duplicate code you'll end up writing otherwise.

Comment: @ZacHowland True, that would significantly reduce the changes I have to make. I'll try it.

Comment: Just keep in mind that, since the STL containers do not have virtual destructors, you don't want to add data members (so you would have to modify your template to be something like `template<typename T, std::size_t N> circular_deque : public std::deque<T> {...};`

Comment: @ZacHowland Thanks, got it working and inheriting deque.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each inline member of a template class must be prefaced with the template parameter list. Ie. this:

```
CircularDeque<class dequeClass>::CircularDeque(int newMax) {
    max = newMax;
}
```

should be this:

```
template<class dequeClass>
CircularDeque<dequeClass>::CircularDeque(int newMax) {
    max = newMax;
}
```

Do that for all of your out-of-class definitions.

Comment: Thank you very much, it compiles now. I'll accept the answer when I can, it hasn't been long enough yet.

Answer (score 0):

Put your function definitions inline or prepend them  with a template declaration like this:

```
template<typename dequeClass>
CircularDeque<class dequeClass>::CircularDeque(int newMax) {
    max = newMax;
}
```